# Syntax error on tutorial

Tags: java, syntax, void

From looking at the code [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ProgressBarDemoProject/src/components/ProgressBarDemo.java) I can see there is a problem with the the first method declaration

```
public Void doInBackground()
```

`void` is capitalized when I would have expected to see it in small caps.

Later on in the same method I see `return null;` which causes me to wonder wether `Void` is a class similar to Integer, Character, etc.

Can anyone confirm this theory?

If Void is a class, when would it be used?

Comment: Void *must* be capitalised in that example.

Comment: You don't need a theory; just read the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html

Comment: If you're going to claim there's a problem, it's worth checking first. The code compiles without errors. It's absolutely fine to *expect* to see it as `void`, but you shouldn't claim it's an error without checking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's correct - it's a method with a return type of [`java.lang.Void`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html).

It *has* to have that return type, because it's extending `SwingWorker<Void, Void>`, and overriding this method:

```
protected abstract T doInBackground() throws Exception
```

The code compiles fine - there's no syntax error.

`Void` is rarely used other than for this sort of situation.

Answer (score 0):

`Void` class is used to represent `void` return keyword in java